# How to recover deleted partition table information

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I have booted my system from a live usb (ubuntu 12.04 64 bit) and while I was going to format a certain partition on my hard drive, I accidentally deleted the partition table {disk utility --> selected my partition from the menu on left side of the window --> format (at the upper center part of the window) --> I select partition table --> and hit format}. Now it doesn't show any partitions (see attachment). and says "unallocated space" whereas it is allocated and there is data that are really important and I cannot afford to lose.
I want to ask is there any way out to recover this information. I have already used testdisk and it has found three partitions successfully whereas the fourth one is still missing. If you recommend using the same software (testdisk) kindly guide me how can I find the fourth one as well and how can I recover them later on (after finding the right partitions). I don't know if it is duplicate or not but as far as I have searched on this site, most of the posts were not helpful. Posts related to testdisk has worked for me to some extent but still I am confused. If you mind asking like this, kindly remove this question. I don't mind. Sorry for any inconvenience caused. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This question is indeed a duplicate, there are already good guides out there for this purpose. If the problem with the 4th partition remains then you might wish to post a question specifically on that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stop using the disk immediately. And don't do anything to it unless you are sure it will result in your disk's partition recovery, otherwise you may harm your data when attempting to recover it.

After that, all the testdisk related posts are useful for the specific case, as you mention. And for your specific case please have a look at this video by Amzertech in Youtube, which explains exactly what to do when deleting a partition the way you did.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg

If everything is fine and you have not done anything harmful to your disk, there are good chances for you to bring the whole partition back with ease, after which I will suggest you to back up everything, format the disk again and place the data inside of it, in order to avoid crossed clusters and these things. Which reminds me that if your hard disk drive is having crossed clusters or data you may lose a lot of information.

Give testdisk a chance and please inform if you succeed on it by commenting on the answers to your question.

Good luck!